# Confusion with representing set of sets in Java?

Tags: java, set

I want to write program that returns the power set of a set. My initial method signature is this: `private static Set<Set<Integer>> generate(Set<Integer> s)` Firstly, I have question about the method signature: about the type of the paramether in the method - should it be `Set<Integer> s` or I have to be more specific and write something like `HashSet<Integer> s`? Second, what should be the return type of my method? Can I write as a return type `Set<Set<Integer>>` or this is not a good practice, and I have to be more specific, i.e. to write something like `HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>`?

Another thing that is not quite clear for me: If I leave my method signature like this:

`private static Set<Set<Integer>> generate(Set<Integer> s)`

then I want to return some set of sets which will be the result. So I wrote something like this:

`Set<Set<Integer>> res = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();`

but the compiler complains. Why I can not create `res` like this way, and what is the best choice for returning the result in this question. And what are the ways to represent set of sets in Java?

Comment: You should create a wrapper class for complex data structures. You can write Set<Integer> as parameter, so this method will expect any class that implements Set<Integer>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question about `Set<Integer>` vs `HashSet<Integer>`, you should definitely choose `Set<Integer>` because:

- is an interface, which can be replaced with any of its implementations such as : HashSet, TreeSet , etc. ; So you should not constrain your method only to accept `HashSet<Integer>`

You could go even further and use something like `Set<? extends Number>` . That way, you could call your method on different sets such as : `Set<Long> , Set<Integer> , etc.`

Regarding your second question about return type : you should again use the most abstract return type ( `Set<Set<Integer>>` , not the specific implementations `HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>`)

About your 3rd question: "Why I can not create res like this way?"

```
Set<Set<Integer>> res = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();
```

That's because the compiler expects a matching between the generic types . For instance you can neither do : `Set<Number> set = new HashSet<Long>();` even though `Long` extends `Number` because it hasn't the same type which was defined by variable declaration, `Number` in this case.

If you really want to be able to call : `new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>()`; you must do :

```
Set<? extends Set<Integer>> set = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();
```

By using the wildcard, you specify to the compiler that you're using something which implements the Set interface.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps! And what if I want to stay consistent with the returning type `Set<Set<Integer>>`? Is `Set<? extends Set<Integer>> set = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();` the only/the best way to define my `res`?

Comment: If you want to be consistent, and I really recommend so, the best approach would be to use : `Set<Set<Integer>>` as your returning type, and declare the res variable in this way : `Set<Set<Integer>> set = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();` This way, you won't have any complains from the compiler, and you will be able to add different kinds of sets to your `res` variable. For instance you could perfectly do : `res.add(new TreeSet<Integer>());` but also : `res.add(new HashSet<Integer>());`

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<Set<Integer>> res = new HashSet<HashSet<Integer>>();
```

As per your requirement you are going to create set of set. But you are trying to create set of hashset. So Complier wont allow to do. Because set of set means outer set may contain any set implementation. So You should not restrict to set of hashset.

```
Set<Set<Integer>> res = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Alternatively, in Java 7+ you could just write `Set<Set<Integer>> res = new HashSet<>();`